# OpenAPI 3, file download, content-type when content is not known in advance

Tags: swagger, openapi

I am building a web service for uploading/downloading files.  There is no restriction on the type of files.

In the OAS 3.0 specifications [(OAS 3.0 specifications, describing responses)](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/) document it has an example of downloading a .pdf file.  (see "Response that Returns a File" and the image I pasted just below).

What do you put in *content* when you don't know in advance what kind of file the server will return?

The specifications for upload suggest that the *schema:* should be *type:binary* and *format:binary*, ok, but for the content type?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: iana.org suggests application/octet-stream for "arbitrary binary data"